# Unrecognized selector sent to instance,UITabBarController pushViewController:animated:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZwcB.png)I am getting some issue. My issue is like this:

> UITabBarController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7a4d05c0.

This problem is connected to screen timeout. After 30 seconds of no activity, my App have to back to the login screen, and if the user come back he have to login again. I am using Tabbar controller. In tabbar controller, I am providing three tabs. If I click first tab displaying login screen...

This is my code.

```
-(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif
{

    NSLog (@"time exceeded!!");

    UIViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    //I've tried a few varieties of the if statement to no avail. Always goes to else.

    if ([controller isViewLoaded]) {

        NSLog(@"Already there!");

    }

    else {

         NSLog(@"go home");

        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

        //[(TIMERUIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] resetIdleTimer];

     }

}
```

Comment: Which line exactly cause the issue ? The "else"? It's because `self.window.rootViewController` is a `UITabBarController` object, not a `UINavigationController` one.

Comment: @Larme      [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; this line i got exception

Comment: Your  self.window.rootViewController is not a  UINavigationController objecti instead its a UITabbarController object. If you have not wrap your LoginController object inside a UINavigationController, then make a  UINavigationController object and set your LoginController instance as its rootViewController and check. I suppose you are pushing to your tabbar controller from login screen.

Comment: @Muneeba thanks for your response. but i cant understand clearly. can you give me any sample code.?

Comment: Attach screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: @Muneeba i am adding my screen shot. please check it once and tel me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to make your login screen a part of `UITabbarController`. When user login successfully, push the tabbar that will contain all the tabs that user can explore and when the time gets out, through back the user to login screen. For this approach i am attaching the storyboard screenshot.[image]

And when times get out, call the following code from any of your view controller that is part of your tabbarcontroller.

`self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true);`

OR you can create a BaseUIViewController class where you can put this time out related code and inherit all of the `UIViewController` from this that are part of your `UITabbarController`.

Comment: If  you still want to make login screen part of your UITabbarController then when time runs out, forcefully change the selected tab of your UITabbarController to your login tab  and disable rest of the tabs so that user can't select them and once user logged in , enable them. But that shouldn't be the approach because login screen is not always available, we present them as per need.

Comment: thanks for your response..thank u so much. very good guidance